# Как не обрабатывать пустой запрос на поиск?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть страница поиска

```
function find($name = '', $nm_nabor = '', $art = '', $factory = '')
{
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "***");
    mysql_select_db("***", $db);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arts WHERE productName LIKE '%$name%' AND collection LIKE '%$nm_nabor%' AND art LIKE '%$art%' AND factory LIKE '%$factory%' ", $db);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Запрос на выборку данных из базы не прошел. Напишите об этом администратору exe1389@mail.ru. <br> <strong>Код ошибки:</strong>";
        exit(mysql_error());
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo '<table width="0" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">';
        echo '<tr><td>название</td><td>набор</td><td>артикул</td><td>фабрика</td><td>цена</td><td>ссылка на страницу откуда была взята информация</td></tr>';

        while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<tr><td>' . $myrow['productName'] . '</td><td>' . $myrow['collection'] . '</td><td>' . $myrow['art'] . '</td><td>' . $myrow['factory'] . '</td><td>' . $myrow['price'] . '</td><td>' . $myrow['link'] . '</td></tr>';
        }

        echo '<table>';
    } else {
        echo 'Поиск не принес результатов! Измините параметры поиска.';
    }
}
function create_select()
{
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "amdstudiru_bot", "185800");
    mysql_select_db("amdstudiru_bot", $db);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT factory FROM arts", $db);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Запрос на выборку данных из базы не прошел. Напишите об этом администратору exe1389@mail.ru. <br> <strong>Код ошибки:</strong>";
        exit(mysql_error());
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $myrow['factory'] . '">' . $myrow['factory'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
}

if ($_POST['status'] == "finding") {
    parse_str($_POST['param'], $output);
    $productName = $output['name'];
    $collection  = $output['name_nabor'];
    $art         = $output['art'];
    $factory     = $output['fabrica'];
    find($productName, $collection, $art, $factory);

}

if ($_POST['status'] == "spisok") {
    create_select();
}
```

Что добавить, чтобы пустой запрос на поиск не обрабатывался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поиском занимается фукнция find, вот и вставьте условие:

```
if(!empty($productName) AND !empty($collection))
{
find($productName, $collection, $art, $factory); 
}
else
{
echo'пустой поисковый запрос';
}
```

Вообще, конечно, так лучше не делать, но поскольку весь поиск сделан криво (это обнаружится чуть позже, когда, например, нужно будет результаты поиска постранично вывести), такое решение будет вполне уместно.

Comment: а как поставить в этом запросе запрет на вывод результата?

Answer (score 0):

А что явзяется "пустым" запросом? какие поля должны быть не заполнены, чтобы запрос считался пустым?
Нужно проверять на пустоту эти поля перед

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arts WHERE productName LIKE '%$name%' AND collection LIKE '%$nm_nabor%' AND art LIKE '%$art%' AND factory LIKE '%$factory%' ", $db);
```

Comment: нужно чтобы проверялись 2 поля '%$name%' AND '%$factory%', но так чтобы если в одном были данные, то в другом можно было не ставить